# iOS - Orientation change - Optical illusion or element moving?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, animation, orientation

I'm wondering about the dynamic animation in iOS when I turn the orientation. E.g. on my iPad, the animation looks very "true" in the menu. The elements (apps, folders, docks, background image, status bar, ...) seem to slide to the right place in a perfect aesthetic way...
But in the App Store I recognized a deviation because the app list has another arrangement.
My big question: Is the orientationChangeAnimation an optical illusion at all or is it really so dynamic? In the App Store it looks like the actual screen is turning and at the same time its alpha value is reducing and the landscape/portrait orientation of the changed screen is doing the same reverse (turning at the same pivot with increasing the alpha value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the Springboard does move things around (like the dock), and it also cross-fades items (like most of the app icons).

Since `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` are called inside an animation block during rotation, you can simply assign new values to animatable properties like alpha and frame. Unless you want explicit control over timing, there's no need for explicit `animateWithDuration:animations:`calls; iOS will automatically animate them for you during rotation.

As an example, in the following code, the red and green squares cross-fade in the center of the screen, and the blue square moves between top-left, and top-center, during the rotation.

```
CGRect b = self.view.bounds;
self.greenLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(b.size.width / 2 - 50, b.size.height / 2 - 50, 100, 100)];
self.greenLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
self.greenLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.greenLabel];

self.redLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.greenLabel.frame];
self.redLabel.autoresizingMask = self.greenLabel.autoresizingMask;
self.redLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.redLabel];

self.blueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.blueLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.blueLabel];

...

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
  if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
    self.greenLabel.alpha = 0;
    self.redLabel.alpha = 1;
    self.blueLabel.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width - 100) / 2, 20, 100, 100);
  } else {
    self.greenLabel.alpha = 1;
    self.redLabel.alpha = 0;
    self.blueLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah thats actually really easy to do and I have done similar things on a lot of my apps. If you wanted to replicate the functionality you can do this:

In the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method or in the viewWillLayoutSubviews method you can do either of these:

```
//Fade out
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^ {
    yourController.view.alpha = 0.2;
}];

//Fade In
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^ {
    yourController.view.alpha = 1.0;
}];

//Fade out fade in
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 animations:^ {
    yourController.view.alpha = 0.2;
}];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 animations:^ {
    yourController.view.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

Cheers,

Sam